# How to compare Hostnames and boolean values in JavaScript with if/else to execute in Mongo Shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, if-statement, mongo-shell

I need to compare Host names from two expressions in Java script using if/else(to be executed in Mongo Shell) and print the result.

#### Snippet I:

for Ex: In MongoDB,

i) `rs.isMaster().primary.split(":").shift()` returns *primary host name* as shown below:

```
MongoDB Enterprise replica001:PRIMARY> rs.isMaster().primary.split(":").shift()

TEST-HOST1
```

ii) `db.hostInfo().system.hostname` returns *current host name*

```
MongoDB Enterprise replica001:PRIMARY> db.hostInfo().system.hostname

TEST-HOST1
```

Now in general terms:

```
if current_hostname= Primary_host_name {
  print('Node connected is Primary');
} else {
  print('Node connected is NOT Primary');
}
```

Code:

```
if(rs.isMaster().primary.split(":").shift() == db.hostInfo().system.hostname) {
  print("Node Connected is Primary");
} else {
  print("Node Connected is NOT Primary");
}
```

But in the output I am getting below error:

```
2021-01-13T01:01:29.016+0530 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script @(shell):1:77

Node Connected is Primary

2021-01-13T01:01:29.017+0530 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'else' @(shell):1:0

Node Connected is NOT Primary
```

#### Snippet II:

The following code also returns same error:

```
if(rs.isMaster().ismaster == true) {
  print("Node Connected is Primary");
} else {
  print("Node Connected is NOT Primary");
}
```

Can some one correct the syntax and help me get the code executed.

Comment: `if (rs.isMaster().ismaster) { ...`should work

Answer (score 0):

seems isMaster & hostInfo giving me different values in my home lab:

```
kiko:SECONDARY> if(rs.isMaster().ismaster == true) {   print("Node Connected is Primary"); } else {   print("Node Connected is NOT Primary"); }
Node Connected is NOT Primary
kiko:SECONDARY> if(rs.isMaster().primary.split(":").shift() == db.hostInfo().system.hostname) {   print("Node Connected is Primary"); } else {   print("Node Connected is NOT Primary"); }
Node Connected is NOT Primary
kiko:SECONDARY> if(rs.isMaster().ismaster == true) {   print("Node Connected is Primary"); } else {   print("Node Connected is NOT Primary"); }
Node Connected is Primary
kiko:PRIMARY> if(rs.isMaster().primary.split(":").shift() == db.hostInfo().system.hostname) {   print("Node Connected is Primary"); } else {   print("Node Connected is NOT Primary"); }
Node Connected is NOT Primary
kiko:PRIMARY> db.hostInfo().system.hostname
titan-lab:30001
kiko:PRIMARY> rs.isMaster().primary
localhost:30001
kiko:PRIMARY>
```